# WinDbg function name is not shown while unassembly from address. How Can i show WinDbg function name from address?

Tags: windows, debugging, x86, kernel, windbg

I'm doing kernel debugging to Windows 7 7601 x86.
And i want to show function name from address while doing unassembly command: `u [address]` 
However i expect output like this.

```
1: kd> u 82e82a7a 
nt!NtAcceptConnectPort:
82e82a7a 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

but it didn't appear function name as below image.

```
1: kd> u nt!NtAcceptConnectPort
nt!NtAcceptConnectPort:
82e82a7a 8bff            mov     edi,edi
82e82a7c 55              push    ebp
82e82a7d 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
82e82a7f 64a124010000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000124h]
82e82a85 66ff8884000000  dec     word ptr [eax+84h]
82e82a8c 56              push    esi
82e82a8d 57              push    edi
82e82a8e 6a01            push    1
1: kd> u 82e82a7a 
ReadVirtual: 82e82a7a not properly sign extended
82e82a7a 8bff            mov     edi,edi
82e82a7c 55              push    ebp
82e82a7d 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
82e82a7f 64a124010000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000124h]
82e82a85 66ff8884000000  dec     word ptr [eax+84h]
82e82a8c 56              push    esi
82e82a8d 57              push    edi
82e82a8e 6a01            push    1
```

I've Already installed all symbole file using `.reload /f`.
But i can't find reason why this is.

How can i solve this problem?

And Also `ln 82e82a7a` doesn't work

```
1: kd> ln 82e82a7a  
Browse module 
Set bu breakpoint
```

But `ln nt!NtAcceptConnectPort` works well

```
(82e82a7a)   nt!NtAcceptConnectPort   |  (82e82af7)   nt!AlpcpGetEffectiveTokenMessage Exact matches:     
nt!NtAcceptConnectPort (_NtAcceptConnectPort@24)
```

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. Post the text instead. What about [`ln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ln--list-nearest-symbols-)? Try `ln 82e82a7a`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've already done for this but.. it didn't show function name.

```1: kd> ln 82e82a7a 
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller But using ln as function name it did search well \

```(82e82a7a)   nt!NtAcceptConnectPort   |  (82e82af7)   nt!AlpcpGetEffectiveTokenMessage
Exact matches:
    nt!NtAcceptConnectPort (_NtAcceptConnectPort@24)
```